# Moore-Penrose bound question

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis

Suppose that we are given an equation $Ax=b$. The minimum least-squares solution is of course $x_{m}=A^{\dagger}b$. What I want to know is whether there are known bounds on $||x-x_{m}||$. In the problem I am dealing with I want to estimate $||x||$ and I can find $x_{m}$.

I hope that this is well-known... :)

Comment: It's not widely known that the first, rather simple incarnation of the pseudoinverse was invented by Othello. In Venice. 

Comment: may be I am misunderstanding something but what is "x"  ? it does not exist usually, it it exists then x_m=x ... I mean typically we use least squares when we have MORE equations than variables, so we canNOT find solution in general so we look for approximate solution which is x_m. 

Comment: @Will Jagy: ???

Comment: @Alexander Chervov:  This is a theoretical problem where I do know that $x$ exists and am trying to bound it. Basically, I'm trying to sort-of-generalize a well-known method to assess the effect of a perturbation of a Markov chain on the stationary distribution. 

Comment: assume Ax=b, then A'Ax=A'b hence x=inv(A'A)A'b so it x=pseudoinverse*b

Comment: @Felix Goldberg: It's a spelling joke.

Comment: Oh, I got it now! Othello the Moor! :)



Comment: @Mark, I was trying to point out the spelling error, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse 

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._H._Moore 

Comment: Now I see it (fixed).



Comment: You can add any element in the kernel of $A$ to $x_m$ to obtain some $x$ which solves $Ax=b$. How can you expect to be able to bound $\|x\|$?

Comment: @Will: yes, I got that: you pointed out the typo by making a joke.  (Of course either one of us could have simply fixed the typo ourselves.)

Comment: @Mark, I kind of thought you understood because you included the word spelling in your first response, but I wasn't sure. Meanwhile, both you and Felix would, in theory, get notified of responses (the little envelope at the top going orange). The orange envelope does not seem to be working for me lately. Sometimes it takes a few hours to figure it out. But it said nothing about your comment, listed as 3 hours ago.  Oh, I don't edit things as much as I did a year ago, partly because it then puts my name on the post under the "active" ordering. 

Answer (score 2):

If $Ax=b$ has a unique solution $x^{*}$, then $x_{m}=x^{*}$.

If $Ax=b$ has infinitely many solutions, then $x_{m}$ will be one of these solutions.  In particular, it will be the solution with the smallest two-norm.  There will be other solutions $x$ such $\| x-x_{m} \|$ is arbitrarily large.

If $Ax=b$ has no solutions then it isn't clear at all what you mean by referring to a specific $x$.

Are you asking about what happens in the presence of noise in $A$ or the right hand side vector $b$?  In these cases the condition number of $A$ can be used to bound the effect of the noise on the pseudoinverse solution.  Unfortunately, if $\mbox{cond}(A)=\infty$, there is no bound.

Comment: can you comment why if many solutions then x_m will have smallest 2-notm ? 

Comment: Alexander- this is an important property of the pseudoinverse solution that can be found in many textbooks.  For example, it's in Strang's "Linear Algebra and its Applications."  There isn't room in this comment for a complete proof, but the key point is that any least squares solution $x_{LS}$ can be written uniquely as $x_{LS}=x_{m}+x_{n}$, where $x_{m}$ (the pseudoinverse inverse solution) is in $R(A^{T})$ and $x_{n}$ is in $N(A)$.  Since $N(A) \perp R(A^{T})$, $\| x_{LS} \|^{2}=\| x_{m} \|^{2}+ \| x_{n} \|^{2}$, and $\| x_{LS} \|$ is minimized when $x_{n}=0$.  

Comment: It should also be clear that you can add any vector in $N(A)$ to $x_{m}$ to get another least squares solution.  Thus if $N(A)$ is nontrivial, then the set of least square squares solutions is unbounded.  